# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, user-controls

I have some user controls in the project kept under a folder UserControls.

I'm using one of the user control from that folder in my master page and one on Default.aspx. The default.aspx uses that master file.

The problem is that everything was working fine until something happened and it seems user control is not getting compiled. The user control calls a method from Business Logic which was parameterless before (when everything was working fine) but when I changed it to accept parameters and of course its calls too, it started giving the error. It is still searching for that parameterless method..!! :(

I did tried manually deleting the DLLs, deleting the user controls and again creating them. But nothing worked.

Anyone has any idea what I did wrong or what am I missing??

Comment: Have you tried manually deleting your "bin" and "obj" folders and rebuilding the solution? That's usually the first thing I try in that situation.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the build configuration manager (Visual Studio 2008 -> Build -> Build Configuration Manager). I ran into a similar issue and it turned out that one of the projects I was referencing was not marked to actually build (there is a check box that should be checked to build the assembly). Try changing the assembly version number of the assembly that is creating the issue, rebuild, then check that the version number of that assembly is correct.

Comment: I DID IT DIDNT WROK

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and it was due to the fact an older version of my bin-deployed assembly existed in the GAC. Unfortunately there is no way to force DLLs to load from the bin directory if the GAC version has the same version number. See here: [Dll in both the bin and the gac, which one gets used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981142/dll-in-both-the-bin-and-the-gac-which-one-gets-used)