# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found ,when i call sendEmail method in my repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am trying to implement an email service . I have a repository class as you can see :

```
 ConfigRepository objConfigRepository = new ConfigRepository();

      public bool SendMail(Message message, List<User> lstUser)
      {
          bool result = true;
          try
          {
              foreach (User item in lstUser)
              {
                  int reciverId = item.Id;
                  var ConfigMail = objConfigRepository.GetAll().First();
                  //var user = objUserRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == reciverId).First();

                  WebMail.SmtpServer = ConfigMail.SmtpServer;
                  WebMail.SmtpPort = int.Parse(ConfigMail.SmtpPort);
                  WebMail.EnableSsl = ConfigMail.EnableSsl;
                  WebMail.UserName = ConfigMail.Username;
                  WebMail.Password = ConfigMail.Password;
                  WebMail.From = ConfigMail.From;

                  WebMail.Send(to: item.Email, subject: message.Title, body: message.MsgText);

              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              result = false;
          }

          return result;

      }

    }
```

As you can see the `sendmail` expects 2 parameters `message` and `userinfo`.In my controller i call this method like this :

```
  objEmailRepository.SendMail(message, lstUser);
```

But i got this error :

```
Method not found: 'Void System.Web.Helpers.WebMail.Send(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>, Boolean, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>)'.
```

Best regards

Comment: The error is in this line:  `WebMail.Send(to: item.Email, subject: message.Title, body: message.MsgText); ` you´re missing some params

Comment: You know i put a breakpoint but the error is happened here   objEmailRepository.SendMail(message, lstUser);
 and it doesn't pass the line that you point

Comment: What is version you used System.Web.Helpers? Maybe your referece's version is not contains this method?

Answer (score 2):

[System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)

Just try to clean and recompile your solution, and make sure you have the latest version of dll in GAC