# Visual Studio Launching

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem I installed visual studio 2013, and I can not create any kind of project.

Method not found: 'Void 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Assert.VSDebug.Log_Tagged (System.String, System.String, System.String, UInt32) '.

Comment: When does it throw this error?  Have you tried reinstalling Visual Studio?  What version of VS are you using?  Have you researched this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to the old version of DLL in the files.Make sure that you have the latest assemblies deployed in the system.You can resolve it by installing  the correct .NET Framework version.Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)