# C# get Property method not found

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-framework-version

I have a project (class library project) with target version .NET Framework 3.5.
I am accessing a string (SplittedPermanentAddressAsString) using get method

```
 if (!Util.isEmpty(cardDetails.SplittedPermanentAddressAsString))
            {
                permanentAddressStr += cardDetails.SplittedPermanentAddressAsString;
            }
```

and here is the Property

```
 public string SplittedPermanentAddressAsString
    {
        get
        {
            if (PermanentAddress != null)
            {
                return PermanentAddress.SplittedFullAdrsEn;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
```

When i run the application, i find following error

"Method not found: 'System.String **HSDLServerAdminLib.Entity.Card.CardDetails.get_SplittedPermanentAddressAsString()'**.
Stack Trace:    at HSDLAdminPortal.ServiceImpl.Card.CardViewDetailImpl.viewDetailInfo(Object view, Object res)
   at HSDLAdminPortal.Controller.Card.CardDetailsController.worker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)

Comment: Could it be possibly an old dll issue? Have you added the method recently? You could try clean solution, delete obj folders and build again. Also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found,

Comment: few methods are added after this change & those are okay, but not the above one,
clean & rebuild is not working, any better suggestion?

Comment: @GhostDeveloper did you get any solution.. i'm facing the same issue