# What does System.MissingMethodException mean and how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, xamarin.forms

I have an error appearing when I run my Xamarin.Forms mobile app which says

```
System.MissingMethodException:Method 'Microsoft.Windows.Azure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor' not found.
```

For the life of me I can't work out what has gone wrong or is going wrong and how to fix it.  The message looks to be self explanitory but I've checked everything that I can think of and MobileServiceClient seems to be present.

[image]

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Well, it appears that `MobileServiceClient` doesn't have a constructor that takes only a single object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)

Comment: I think it might be from the fact that they got rid of a bunch of constructors for version 10. Compare [v10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/JJ553674(v=azure.10).aspx) to [v9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/JJ553674(v=azure.9).aspx). I bet your code is compiled against v9 but it is using v10 on azure. I have never used xamarin.forms so I have no idea how to fix it. @ChrisDunaway I think the problem is it used to have a constructor that did, now it has a constructor that takes a single object and a params parameter.

Comment: Is there any easy way for me to make the comparison against all my versions? Is there are tool or just something to be done manually with nuget packet manager?