# Activator.CreateInstance(type) Throws Exception

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, .net-native

Actually it is very strange exception, because it happens only when I build the project as **Release** and does not happen at all when I choose **Debug**. In debug mode, the app works perfect and the following code works well.

**Here is the code of my extension method:**

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(this T source) where T : UIElement
{
   T result;

   // Get the type
   Type type = source.GetType();

   // Create an instance
   result = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T; //throws exception here only if I build project as (release)

   CopyProperties<T>(source, result, type);
   DeepCopyChildren<T>(source, result);

   return result;
}
```

**The exception is:**

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   System.Private.Reflection.Execution.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: MissingConstructor_Name,
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel. For more information, visit
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

I've found some related questions to this exception, but they all are pointing to missing libraries or update libraries like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found) but didn't change anything in my app.

Comment: Unrelated, but `as T` is useful when the result might not be of type `T`. Functionality-wise, `x as T` means `x is T ? (T) x : null`, except that `x` is only evaluated once. You know that `x is T` is necessarily always true, and in the unlikely event that you made a mistake there somewhere, getting an exception immediately makes for easier debugging than a `NullReferenceException` somewhere inside `CopyProperties`. Therefore, I recommend `(T) Activator.CreateInstance(type)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is related to the fact that Release build of UWP apps uses the **.NET native toolchain**. In this mode **reflection** needs some hints to work properly. Aparently the constructor of the `RelativePanel` is not available for reflection.

Luckily there is a workaround for this as described in [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/21/net-native-deep-dive-help-i-hit-a-missingmetadataexception/).

In your UWP project's Properties folder is a file called `default.rd.xml`. Open it and add the following line inside the `<Applications>` element:

```
<Type Name="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel" 
      Dynamic="Required All" Activate="Required All" />
```

The `Dynamic` attribute should ensure reflection is possible and the `Activate` attribute should ensure the constructors are available for activation - which is key for your case.

This should include all members of `RelativePanel` for reflection and everything should work as expected.

You can see more details on the `default.rd.xml` file structure [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600639.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, actually I tried your fix, clean solution and build (release) but unfortunately still getting the same.

Comment: Then I would suggest trying make a dummy a method, that will just create an instance of `RelativePanel` (`new RelativePanel()`) and maybe call a method or set a property on it. Then recompile in Release and see if the type is now present or not.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another attribute that should actually fix your issue :-) - the `Activate` attribute.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot, after Adding (Activate) I've got exceptions for each control / element inside the relative panel (Image, Ellipse .. etc), then added all same what did with RelativePanel, then problem solved :)

Comment: Awesome :-D ! It is probably possible to add an entire namespace by using the `Namespace` attribute, so you can save yourself some time and maintenance :-) .

Comment: You can also use the Subtype version of the directives to apply the policy to all subtypes of the given type.