# AutoMapper - Cannot map between IdentityUser subclass and its correspondant DTO

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, automapper

I'm working on a project with asp.net core and Identity,
I am trying to create a mapping configuration between IdentityUser subclasse and its correspondant DTO using Automapper
I have done similar configuration with other classes and it works fine, but with IdentityUser subclass it behaves differently :

Here is my IdentityUser subclasse :

```
public partial class Collaborateur : IdentityUser
{
    public Collaborateur() : base()
    {
        this.Activites = new HashSet<ActiviteCollaborateur>();
        this.ActeursAvantVente = new HashSet<ActeurAvv>();
    }

    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Matricule { get; set; }
    public string Structure { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public RoleEnum Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActiviteCollaborateur> Activites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ActeurAvv> ActeursAvantVente { get; set; }
    public virtual Agence Agence { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
}
```

Its corresponding DTO :

```
public class CollaborateurDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Matricule { get; set; }
    public string Structure { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public RoleEnum Role { get; set; }
}
```

CollaborateurProfile config class :

```
public class CollaborateurProfile : Profile
{
    CollaborateurProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Collaborateur, CollaborateurDTO>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Collaborateur, Collaborateur>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.CreatedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.LastModified, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => DateTime.UtcNow));
    }
}
```

and Startup.cs :

`services.AddAutoMapper();`

it stops at this line with

MissingMethodException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Can you try deleting bin and obj folders from your project, recompiling the project, and running again? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found

Answer (score 0):

By mistake i answered this question at the question linked in the comments (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46567611/7131186)

Here is my answer:

In my case (and it seems that this is your case too) it was a copy/paste problem. I somehow ended up with a PRIVATE constructor for my mapping profile:

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Animal, AnimalDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

(take note of the missing "public" in front of the ctor)

which compiled perfectly fine, but when AutoMapper tries to instantiate the profile it can't (of course!) find the constructor!