# System.MissingMethodException Unit Test

Tags: .net-core, mstest, visual-studio-2017, xunit, .net-4.7

Having what appears to be runtime issues with **Project References** in Visual Studio 2017 Test Runner. The Unit Test **CSPROJ** builds just fine with `TargetFramework=net47`, but at execution time we get the following message from MSTEST or XUNIT. Using `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` v15.0.0.

#### Test Execution Error (x86): Serilog Seq Extension

> System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Serilog.LoggerConfiguration Serilog.SeqLoggerConfigurationExtensions.Seq(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerSinkConfiguration, System.String, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, Int32, System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1, System.Nullable`1<Int64>, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, System.Nullable`1, Boolean, Int32)'.

#### Unit Test Example - Serilog

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();    
    loggerConfig.MinimumLevel.Debug();                    
    loggerConfig.WriteTo.LiterateConsole();    
    loggerConfig.WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:65454");    
}
```

If we reference `net462` projects, we get the same result so we believe it is related to VS 2017, not .NET Framework version. We have never seen this error with VS 2015. Seems like there is an issue loading DLL extensions with optional parameters / matching signatures, etc. The method clearly exists or it wouldn't compile - why at runtime is this crashing out?

If I just use local nuget packages it works fine - this only seems to be a problem when referencing any Projects via `ProjectReference` in .NET Core CSPROJ. It doesn't seem to handle the dependency tree properly.

Another example using `KeyVault` where VS Test Runner cannot find the extension methods properly...

#### Test Execution Error (x86): KeyVault Extension

> Message: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient..ctor(AuthenticationCallback, System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[])'.

#### Unit Test Example - KeyVault

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    KeyVaultClient _kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new AuthenticationCallback(getKeyVaultToken));
}

private static async Task<string> getKeyVaultToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential("test", "account");
    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).Result;

    if (result == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Discovered this odd issue with [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-test) is two-fold. After running `dotnet test --diag` and reviewing the output, it led me to realize there are [newer releases of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/releases) which version `15.0.0` was masking the real problem. Once I upgraded the nuget to `15.3.0-preview-20170502-03`, a different exception appeared.

#### Error Source: Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.'

Now this is interesting - the `MissingMethodException` was masking the real problem which was buried in `System.Net.Http`. The second realization is that this [base library has a bug which prevents the type from being loaded](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2960190/azurekeyvaultprovider-incomplatible-with-system-net-http-4-1). Once I [nuget updated `System.Net.Http` to version `4.3.1`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11100), the issue went away and my Project References started working again.

#### Conclusion

Update [`Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK` to latest preview](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/15.3.0-preview-20170502-03) and [`System.Net.Http` to latest version](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) to get past the weird `MissingMethodException` with **dotnet test**. You can [track the open issue on github here](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/6).

#### Option #2 - Excluding Package Reference Assets

For latest VS 2017 `CSPROJ` formats - the following config also fixes this as it supresses copying `System.Net.Http` to the **Build Output** path which by default loads the GAC'd version `4.0.0.0`.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.1">
  <ExcludeAssets>All</ExcludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

#### Option #3 - Assembly Binding Redirect

`dotnet` core will follow any runtime binding redirects you place in your `app.config`, so any nuget dependencies you have to `System.Net.Http` to version `4.1.*`, you can redirect to the latest version or revert to the last stable version `4.0`.

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <!-- Another PackageReference dependency binds to 4.1.1 which is busted, we leverage .NET Core redirection and revert to CLR 4.0.0 -->
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Had this same issue `MissingMethodException` in powershell...turns out that if you downgrade `System.Net.Http` to target version `4.0.0.0` (GAC'd) it will revert the security issue in newer versions.

Comment: `System.MissingMethodException` was failing my unit tests in `.NetFramework` project only on Windows machine, on Mac they passed perfectly. Adding a reference to a `Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK` packaged had solved the issue for me.

Comment: Just spent a day trying to figure out the same problem with Azure Key Vault failing with missing method exception for the constructor when running a unit test with VS Test Explorer - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I encountered this issue while testing a class from a project that had a dependency on a Nuget package that had been updated in the project being tested, but not in the test project (which was the source for the missing method).**

The solution was as simple as upgrading the affected Nuget in the test project:

```
Right-Click the test project > Manage Nuget packages > Upgrade necessary packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a SharePoint plug-in and the plug-in has been installed on the server that I am also using to do development.  Therefore, I think the DLL is in the GAC and that DLL is being picked up first!

I was getting the MissingMethodException from the test runner.  So I came up with an easy fix.

**Change the version number in AssemblyInfo.cs!**  This will make the version number in the GAC and the one in your bin/Release directory different, so the test runner will use the correct DLL.  Phew!

See also:

[System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found/36344325)