# How to resolve the Method not found in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio, xlsx

I'm trying to read an xlsx file, and I got a basic overview from [This Codeproject Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801032/Csharp-How-To-Read-xlsx-Excel-File-With-Lines-Of-C)

Now, I'm getting the following exception message: 
[image: Exception Message]

The code segment related to this exception is given below:

```
public static sst SharedStrings;

    /// <summary>
    /// All worksheets in the Excel workbook deserialized
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ExcelFileName">Full path and filename of the Excel xlsx-file</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<worksheet> Worksheets(string ExcelFileName)
    {
        worksheet ws;
        using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(ExcelFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            SharedStrings = DeserializedZipEntry<sst>(GetZipArchiveEntry(zipArchive, @"xl/sharedStrings.xml"));
            foreach (var worksheetEntry in (WorkSheetFileNames(zipArchive)).OrderBy(x => x.FullName))
            {
                ws = DeserializedZipEntry<worksheet>(worksheetEntry);
                ws.NumberOfColumns = worksheet.MaxColumnIndex + 1;
                ws.ExpandRows();
                yield return ws;
            }
        }
    }
```

After some searching, I figured out that I needed to target .NET 4.5 or above version, (I'm targetting 4.6.1, but I also have tried 4.5, still same results). Also, as far as the dependencies are concerned, my references look like this:
[image: References Image]

After doing all this, I'm still getting the exception mentioned above, and have no idea why this is happening.

EDIT 1: I've been through [This StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found), where I figured that I need the latest DLLs. I went to the Nuget Package Manager, and there were "No Packages Found" which were available for the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried `.NET 4.6.1` and `4.6.2.` Both work OK for me.

My `Visual Studio` is `Community Edition 2017`

The project references:

[image]

**Note** that `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` is **not** referenced. It was not possible to reference it in my environment.

Use `Workbook.Worksheets()` or declare the calling class as sub-class of `Excel.Workbook`.

`Excel` is the namespace of the [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/801032/csharp-how-to-read-xlsx-excel-file-with-lines-ofthe) source which provides the necessary classes.

```
using Excel;
using System;

namespace akExcelAsZipDemo
{
    class Program : Workbook
    {
        //  from
        //  https://www.codeproject.com/tips/801032/csharp-how-to-read-xlsx-excel-file-with-lines-ofthe
        //
        //  inspired:
        //  https://github.com/ahmadalli/ExcelReader

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string fileName = @"E:\AK\export.xlsx";

            var worksheets = Worksheets(fileName);

            foreach (worksheet ws in worksheets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"cols={ws.NumberOfColumns} rows={ws.Rows.Length}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but it still isn't working for me. Same exception. The problem arises inside the `var worksheets = Worksheets(fileName);` part.

Comment: Check the `Github` project [ExcelReader](https://github.com/ahmadalli/ExcelReader) and compare, if you copied the source 1:1. Can you debug to pinpoint the exact source code line where the exception gets thrown?

Comment: I have no idea how it did work out, but I definitely copy/pasted the Workbook.cs code again from the github source, cleaned and rebuilt, and it somehow worked out.