# System.MissingMethodException in System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code to extract a single file from a ziparchive.

```
public void ExtractSingleFile(string fileName,string source)
{
    var archive = OpenRead(source);
    var entry = archive.GetEntry(fileName);
    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine("/temp", fileName));
}
```

When running, I get the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Methode not found: Void
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile(System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry,
>   System.String).'

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

I tried cleaning and rebuilding, searched for updates and nuget and re-added the references as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740302/how-to-resolve-the-method-not-found-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the Method not found in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740302/how-to-resolve-the-method-not-found-in-c)

Comment: @Nkosi that would be a compilation error. As a runtime error, it means that the code is compiling against one version, but running with a different version (usually: older) of System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll - one that lacks that method

Comment: @MarcGravell got it. totally missed the `when running` part

Comment: What version of .Net are you running?

Comment: @Nkosi Version 4.6.1

Comment: Stay away from Nuget, you want to have as little to do with .NETCore as you can.  Diagnose this with the Fuslogvw.exe, log all binds and show us the trace for System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll