# Using Moq testing overloaded methods, get System.MissingMethodException: "Method Not Found"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have this interface:

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{

    // Use this method for non transactional commits, and return the new primary key.
    Task<int> CreateNewProductItem(ProductExt product);

    // use this method for transactional commits, and return the new primary key
    Task<int> CreateNewProductItem(ProductExt product, MySqlConnection conn, MySqlTransaction transaction);
```

Now I'm trying to write some Moq setups:

```
            Mock<IProductsRepository> _ProductRepositoryMoq = new Mock<IProductsRepository>();

            _ProductRepositoryMoq.Setup(r => r.CreateNewProductItem(It.IsAny<ProductExt>()))
                .ReturnsAsync((ProductExt p) =>
                {
                    p.ID = productList.Last().ID + 1;
                    return p.ID;
                });
            _ProductRepositoryMoq.Setup(r => r.CreateNewProductItem(It.IsAny<ProductExt>(), It.IsAny<MySqlConnection>(), It.IsAny<MySqlTransaction>()))
                .ReturnsAsync((ProductExt p, MySqlConnection c, MySqlTransaction t) =>
                {
                    p.ID = productList.Last().ID + 1;
                    return p.ID;
                });
```

When I try to run the unit test and before it happens, I get this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Int32> 
  Repositories.ProductManager.IProductsRepository.CreateNewProductItem(ProductManagerModels.ProductExt, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction)'.
```

I don't get it. This method is defined in the usual way and it's clearly visible, so why is Moq throwing a fit that it cannot find CreateNewProductItem(product, MySqlConnection, MySqlTransaction) ??

NOTE: I've already tried nuking all bin/obj in all projects to force VS 2017 to rebuild the entire solution, and although unlikely, I did see if there was a remote possibility that is was in the GAC, but there was not one item from my projects that has been placed into the GAC. Therefore it has be elsewhere.

SECOND NOTE: As I stated, this is happening ***before*** I run any unit tests in the [TestInitialize] method. I'm using MSTest for unit testing. Now the funny thing is that I wrote up a spike to use the database directly instead of the Moq, and NO system.MethodMissingException is thrown. I also verified that the data has indeed been inserted and/or updated in the MySQL Database.

Comment: You have duplicated declaration of `IProductsRepository` instead of code for Moq setup.

Comment: The code samples you've posted are identical apart from the comment..?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just corrected it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found)

Comment: What does your unit test look like?

Comment: @Crowcoder - The unit test is irrelevant since it doesn't even start the test. This error is thrown while I'm in the Test Initializer

Comment: So that is what you mean by "before it happens". That was unclear.

Comment: @SomeUser: I've looked at it and tried what they suggested. None of my code is in the GAC, and I went as far as to deleting all bin/obj folders manually just to force VS to build them up again.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you've posted given the code above.

Comment: @stakx: What version of Moq are you using? I believe I'm using the latest one

Comment: @SteveBrother: In cases such as these, I think it goes without saying that we're talking about the latest version. Obviously, if the problem only happened with an older version, the solution would be to simply upgrade. That being said, have you looked at the question linked [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831031/using-moq-testing-overloaded-methods-get-system-missingmethodexception-method?noredirect=1#comment82625437_47831031)?

Comment: @SteveBrother: Moq just got another incident (reported at https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/566), for which we've identified the culprit. See details in that issue.