# System.MissingMethodException - Setter in Constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, dependency-injection, constructor

I have a unit test which calls a repository with a setter for the user Id of the DataContext. When running the tests, I am encountering a *System.MissingMethodException*.

CrewRepository:

```
public CrewRepository(DataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
{
    dataContext.UserId = (int)UserCode.System;
}
```

APIFixture:

```
services.AddDbContext<CrewAdapter.DataContext>(options => options
    .UseInMemoryDatabase("CrewUnitTestingDatabase")
    .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning)));

services.AddScoped<CrewRepository>(x =>
{
    // This is line 42:
    return new CrewRepository(x.GetRequiredService<CrewAdapter.DataContext>()); 
});
```

CrewRepositoryTests:

```
public void RecordExists_SequenceNumberIsGreaterThanExistingRequest_MarkAsUpdate()
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        APIDataBuilder.PopulateContext(scope);

        var bookingRequest = new BookingRequest
        {
            CrewStaffNumber = "TEST",
            FirstName = "Test Paul",
            MiddleName = "",
            LastName = "Test George",
            Rank = "TEST",
            Appointment = "TEST"
        };

        // This is line 218:
        var result = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<CrewRepository>()
            .CreateBookingRequest(bookingRequest); 

        Assert.Equal((int)BookingRequestStatus.Update, result.Status);
    }
}
```

DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    // *bunch of entities*
}
```

Error Message:

> [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Error] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]     Crew.Tests.Api.Repositories.CrewRequestRepositoryTests.RecordExists_SequenceNumberIsGreaterThanExistingRequest_MarkAsUpdate [FAIL]
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]       System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Crew.DataAdapter.DataContext.set_UserId(Int32)'.
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]       Stack Trace:
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]            at Repositories.CrewRepository..ctor(DataContext dataContext)
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]         C:\Users\source\repos\Crew.Tests\Api\APIFixture.cs(42,0): at Crew.Tests.Api.APIFixture.<>c.<.ctor>b__4_2(IServiceProvider x)
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]            at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProviderEngineScope )
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]            at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]            at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>   [2/4/2020 8:16:50 AM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:01.83]         C:\Users\source\repos\Crew.Tests\Api\Repositories\CrewRequestRepositoryTests.cs(218,0): at Crew.Tests.Api.Repositories.CrewRequestRepositoryTests.RecordExists_SequenceNumberIsGreaterThanExistingRequest_MarkAsUpdate()

Comment: Related: [Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8059594/2791540)

Comment: This is your problem  `dataContext.UserId = (int)UserCode.System;` Can you explain what your are trying to do with this line? Did you potentially want to just store it as a instance member?

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes. so that the user for everything that is saved by the context is set to the system's usercode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataContext` is a `System.Data.Linq` Class. It can't have that field.

You will need to pass it in.

```
public CrewRepository(MyFunkyContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
{
    dataContext.UserId = (int)UserCode.System;
}
```

If your class is actually named `DataContext` then you will likely need to qualify it with a full namespace or a *using alias*, so there is no confusion.

```
public CrewRepository(MyNamesSpace.Somethingelse.DataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
{
    dataContext.UserId = (int)UserCode.System;
}
```

or

```
using DataContext = MyNamesSpace.Somethingelse.DataContext;

public CrewRepository(DataContext dataContext) : base(dataContext)
```

The problem seems to be it's picking the wrong DataContext.

I would suggest naming your `DbContext` as something more specific e.g `MyContext`

Comment: The context is the one that uses it. The Id used depends on the repository.

Comment: edited the question and added the DataContext. It was named as DataContext but Inherits DbContext.