# Xamarin Forms System.MissingMethodException:'Could not find method' System.String[] System.String.Split(Char, System.StringSplitOptions)'

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to test this method with UnitTest, but when I run the test I received the `System.MissingMethodException`.

**My method:**

```cs
public void LoadData()
{
    while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var words = line.Split('\t',StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

**My test:**

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Resource_Load_Data()
{
    int idListato = 3;
    SDictionary sDictionary = new SDictionary(idListato);
    sDictionary.LoadData();            
}
```

I tried many solutions but without success, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using any Nuget package in your project? If yes, try to upgrade packages. And  check if there is any old dll in your project. Refer to the thread [System.MissingMethodException: Method not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found).

Comment: I resolved using a Regex. I have tried to Update NuGet packages but don't fix the problem.