# Service Binder exception: method not found

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, exception, grpc, worker-service

Attempt to launch this: https://github.com/celery94/GrpcHostServer on Visual Studio 16.7.6 gave me following exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IEndpointConventionBuilder Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RoutingEndpointConventionBuilderExtensions.WithDisplayName(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IEndpointConventionBuilder, System.String)'.'

What's causing it and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using, you can refer to this post, which may help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058832/system-missingmethodexception-method-not-found

Comment: Wow, thanksa lot, that actually helped! Can't be;ieve I've missed that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the Nuget packages fixed the issue