# How to stop transitive dependency from appearing in your project

Tags: c#, dll, nuget, dependency-management

For example I use a library **B** from NuGet in my project **A** :

Referencing:

`<PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0"/>`

Usage:

```cs
namespace A.Helpers
{
    public interface Helper
    {
         A.Models.Output DoStuff(B.Input input);
    }
}
```

And also publish it to NuGet. After some time I notice that **B** uses a lot of different unnecessary dependencies like **C**, **D**, ..., **ZZZ** so my NuGet **A** also transitively references them.

If I reference it adding PrivateAssets tag instead:

`<PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>`

Then users of **A** lose access to class **B.Input**

How do I ship library **A** without passing unnecessary dependencies **C**, **D**, ..., **ZZZ** to the end user but still allow using class **B.Input** ?

Edit: I would like to clarify that *unnecessary* here means "not needed for functionality I am using or shipping". i.e. I use matrices and vectors from **B**, but **B** also provides means to work with graphics and references like **System.Drawing** and I prefer to not pass it further

Comment: Talk the maintainer of B that he removes the unnecessary stuff?

Comment: "B uses a lot of different unnecessary dependencies like C, D, ..., ZZZ "      You are either wrong that B needs C,D,ZZZ     OR         or raise an issue (or heaven forbid) do a fork and PR that removes C,D,ZZZ from B.

Comment: @granadaCoder No need to fork it, just unpack the `nupkg`, edit the `nuspec` to remove/exclude any unwanted deps, then re-pack it under a new package-id.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify what I mean on **unnecessary**. For now seems like @Dai solution is the most suitable one for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my flippant comment to an answer because [the OP said it was actually good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77516262/how-to-stop-transitive-dependency-from-appearing-in-your-project?noredirect=1#comment136664029_77516262) <sup>(lol, but fair enough)</sup>)

### Instructions: Break NuGet Package Seal in Event of Misbehaving Package Authors

1. Find the offending `.nupkg` package file (either by copying it from its source, or from your `~/.nuget/packages/` directory.

   - Also check to see if there's a `.snupkg` or `.symbols.nupkg` file too.
2. As a `.nupkg` is just a rebadged zip file, extract its contents to a new directory somewhere; you can use your favourite PKZIP tool (e.g. 7-Zip, [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.3), WinZip, or even `explorer.exe`'s painfully slow extraction wizard).
3. In the root of the extracted contents, locate the `{packageName}.nuspec` file. Open it in Notepad or [your editor of choice](https://briancallahan.net/blog/20200816.html).
4. Edit the `<metadata>`, `<dependencies>` and `<dependency>` elements to your liking. Some tips:

   - Don't confuse [MSBuild `<PackageReference />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) and `<ProjectReference />` with NuSpec `<dependency>` elements - they're similar but also different.

     - e.g. `<dependency>` has `include=""`, `exclude=""` and , while `<PackageReference />` has `IncludeAssets=""`, `ExcludeAssets=""`, and `PrivateAssets=""`.
   - [Consider adding the `developmentDependency="true"` attribute](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/DevelopmentDependency-support-for-PackageReference)

     - Confusingly, there [is also a `<developmentDependency>` element for NuSpec's `<metadata>`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2841) and I'm unsure what it does.
   - Don't forget to change the NuSpec's `<id>` to be globally distinct from the original package you're modifying (the package name does not need to match any assembly names, it's entirely arbitrary).

     - And it's also good-form to append to the `<description>` element to document the changes you made so that other people (and future-you) won't be confused by the existence of `DodgyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg` next to `DodgyPackageNowLessDodgy.0.1.0-dev.nupkg` in the same package store.
5. Then create a new empty `.zip` file, add the files back into it, and rename it to `{yourNewPackageId}.{version}.nupkg` and add it to your package store.

Answer (score 1):

Two Scenarios

1. Even though the dependencies are passed, unless the consumer is using items w/in the other packages, the sub methods are not linked in during runtime.

   - So for that this issue is moot.
2. If the user is *actually* using the other B packages, they should be bringing in the right version of those packages to use, outside of your package, for their code, which will override the B packages.

   - (Again if consumer is using the sub packages): Most likely the consumer should be setting those package[s] to `[get] the latest` version of the ancillary packages as to not get your, most likely lower in the future, version[s].

---

See my response to such a situation here

[c# - System.MissingMethodException: Method not found? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36344325/285795)

Comment: I am partly concerned about runtime here.
I believe that extra dependencies slow down a development process by introducing conflicts, such as using the same class name in multiple packages, and cluttering the implicit references tab in IDEs. Additionally, one might unintentionally use the wrong implementation due to implicit referencing, among other reasons. I sincerely hope my concerns are understood.

Comment: "same class name in multiple packages" - everything a compiler does is processing namespaced objects. Whether one has multiple "Order" classes in a project doesn't slow down the process. As mentioned once linked the *superflous* other classes do not make it into the final code. "one might unintentionally use the wrong implementation" - The consumer has full control to use the proper implementation via versioning while your code uses the proper items due to the same logic of versioning provided. The effect on compilation and eventual running is slight to none in the scenario you described.

Comment: I agree with the idea to not bring in superfluous packages which are not needed; but as long as you have done that for your own code, that is best which can be done.