# How do you place an assembly in the GAC for .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I've got a utility that reads type information from an assembly.  I'm moving this utility to run in .net core.

```
  Assembly foo = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=76823001051318ce"));
```

This assembly is also targeting .net core but I'm loading it into the cache with the 'gacutil' that ships with the SDK.

The utility isn't able to find the assembly I loaded which makes me think: there's probably one GAC for the Framework and another for .NET Core.  So how do you load assemblies so that a .net core application can read the type information dynamically?

**EDIT:** Some of the comments below point to an article on how to deploy libraries using .net core. My question doesn't involve deployment, it involves finding a datatype on the target machine in the GAC.  The prototypical example would be Microsoft's MSDataSetGenerator custom tool which has instructions for columns in an XSD schema file.  The datatype for each column is described by a string that defines the assembly and type used for that column.

```
      <xs:element name="ProvinceId" msdata:DataType="MyNamespace.MyDatatype, mylibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnProvinceId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ProvinceId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ProvinceIdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ProvinceId" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538093/is-there-any-gac-equivalent-for-net-core

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/aspnetcore-2.0#runtime-store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any GAC equivalent for .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538093/is-there-any-gac-equivalent-for-net-core)