# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.NET.HostModel' after .NET Core upgrade

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, msbuild

My .NET Core was recently upgraded from 3.1.402 to 3.1.403; after this update, when i try to run my project with `dotnet run` command, i'm receiving this message:

> [MSBuild solution compiling events] - Error at file
> '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.403/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets',
> from project '{my csproj file path}';
> error associated with lines 424-0; Sender: MSBuild. Code error:
> MSB4018; message: 'The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.NET.HostModel, Version=3.1.6.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04; before the SDK upgrade the project was working fine. Is it some kind of bug from the new version of the .NET Core SDK?

Comment: Did you try a clean build?

Comment: @jdweng Yes! Even after the "dotnet clean" command the error remains.

Comment: Open the csproj file with notepad and check version.  Deleting the reference and then add will fix version or editing the csproj file will also work.

Comment: @jdweng My csproj file contains only _<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>_, it doesn't have any reference to 3.1.402 or 3.1.403.

Comment: Are you using VS 16.7.6?  See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1.  It was just released on the 13th.  See release notes : https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1.9/3.1.9.md

Comment: @jdweng I'm not using Visual Studio, i'm not even using Windows OS. Like i said, i'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616079/how-to-resolve-net-core-package-version-conflicts