# Constant only assembly still required at runtime i dotnetcore

Tags: .net-core, deployment, dependencies

I got an assembly containing only static classes with constants

```
public static class C {
    public const int Value = 123;
}
```

I use this assembly in different applications and it is marked with `CopyLocal = false` and is not deployed.

This work for `netframework` applications but for `netcoreapp` I get an error message saying the assembly can not be found.

The assembly is not referenced in the compiled code (verified with `ildasm`) but there is still a reference in the `.deps.json` file.

Do I need to deploy the assembly with core applications or is there a settings to exclude it from the `.deps.json` file?

(Most of my netframework applications are only small executables so it seemed unnecessary to include a multi-megabyte, not used, assembly in the deploy. Core application are large and multi-file from start so it doesn't matter)

**Edit**: found the problem.
The assembly didn't actually have `CopyLocal = false`. It used a .targets file to remove it at build time

```
<Target Name="PreventConstantsCopyLocal" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" 
                                 Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' == 'MyConstants'" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I just added a an extra condition

```
And ('%(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == '' Or '%(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Full')
```

so the constants are copied to output in core builds.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**
As a general rule you should always use CopyLocal=True, if the reference is not contained within the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

**The Problem:**
When you use an assembly, with `CopyLocal = false` set, it means that the Assembly (.dll file) will not be placed into the output directory of whatever you just built.

What happens next is the following: As soon as the missing assembly is used somewhere in your executing code, the runtime environment will try to load it. for .Net Framework, this happens in a very specific [way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies).

This is different as dotnetcore do. They have no GAC, but there is something called the [Runtime package Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store)

**The Solution:**

Maybe [Is there any GAC equivalent for .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538093/is-there-any-gac-equivalent-for-net-core)

Comment: The issue here is the assembly is not used anywhere in the executing code. The assembly only contain constants which are compiled directly into the code. `In fact, when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code [...] it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants

Comment: i tried to reproduce your situation by creating two assemblies, one assembly (test) with one public constant, 2nd assembly (consumer) referencing the first assembly, copylocal false, and using the constant. when i publish it, the test.dll is not even mentioned in deps.json (and not in the publish directory). i moved that to a machine running dotnetcore and it worked. so i cannot reproduce your problem. i was using dotnetcore 3.1.  sorry, im out. you could maybe try turnin on the "readytorun" option, available from .netcore 3.0, which does some ahead of time compiling for you?

Comment: thanks. Your comment got me on the right track and I found the problem, see my update