# How to retrieve Controller methods from WebApi binaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, reflection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have already compiled and published API (`ASP.NET Core WebAPI` on `.NET5). I would like to retrieve a list of methods in Controller classes, from another Desktop application (WPF). In prior .NET versions I was doing it this way:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes().Where(a => a.FullName != null && a.FullName.StartsWith("MyTestApp.WebApi.Controllers."));
```

... but that doesn't work in `.NET5` because for some reason no all required dlls are copied when building/publishing the project in `.NET5`. So I'm looking for a straight forward way to just get list of methods in a given namespaces.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I have added an answer to what appears to be a related post by you [Microsoft libraries missing when compiling .NET5 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845835/microsoft-libraries-missing-when-compiling-net5-project) hopefully it resolves your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Throw your .dll assemblies in ILSpy or something similar and just decompile them?