# Can I change the already referenced DLL's path?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I am searching for a way to change the DLL's path without having to use `Assembly.LoadFrom` or `.Load`.

I cannot change the code, and it already references DLL's like `Namespace.Class.Method`. Is there a way to change the path of that DLL and tell .net to look for it using a new path? The new path is known, so I just need a way to point it there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the path is already hard-coded, I can't see how you can change that without editing the code, but perhaps there is another alternative:

If you have the correct dll-file (correct name and version number as referenced by .net) in the **Global Assembly Cache** (the "GAC"), then there is a chance .NET might load it from there.

I'm saying it *might* do so, because I'm not sure about how this works if you're explicitly loading a dll directly from code. If the assembly is simply referenced by name / namespace in the normal way though, [it should search for the library in the gac first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981367/336648).

May be worth a shot anyway. You'll find your GAC at: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`

Comment: It is referenced like you said. What I have to do is make .NET search the directory I specify too. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: In that case, I doubt it can be done without changing the source code. Too bad it's hard-coded - it would probably have been a better idea to specify it in a config file which could have been changed more easily...

Comment: How can I specify it in a config file? Sorry I am kind of a newbie.

Comment: Again, you would have to change the source code; if you define some kind of config file (an `app.config`, for instance), you could read the path from there, and pass it to .Net (Assembly.LoadFrom) as a variable instead of having it hard coded; but if as you say, you can't change the code, then this does not help you, sorry!