# How to Develop a software which has extensions

Tags: c#, .net

I want to develop a software which accepts the extension like that of Visual Studio Code. For example Software *S* has default functions *f*, then the extension *e* will help add new feature which will extend the functionality of the software. I searched for tutorials but I was not able to come up with the solution nor a good tutorial. Am I not searching with right tutorial? Please help.

Comment: what version of .net? what type of csproj?

Comment: the version of the .net is 4.8 and the csproj is visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Copy Local" when set to true ensures that the dll for the assembly reference is added to the referencing project's bin folder so that it's available at the run time. If the required dll is not found in the bin folder then, the one in GAC can be used. If even then, the dll is not found, we will encounter errors.

If the same version of the dll exists in bin as well as GAC then, the one from GAC is used but if a different version is used and referenced in the project then the one from bin gets used. Similar question answered in [Dll in both the bin and the gac, which one gets used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981142/dll-in-both-the-bin-and-the-gac-which-one-gets-used)